# Code Runner extension for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

I recently started programming in Lua and I decided to use Visual Studio Code. I run my programs using Code Runner extension for VSC but there is an issue.

When I use a sleep or wait function the program first waits the given time and then executes everything, instead of first executing the program before I call the method, then wait, and then continue.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the programs output that's being delayed?

Comment: Yes, I added a timer to test it as well and the time it takes to compile without the sleep is 0.something while with the sleep(1) it takes 1.something but in both cases the string is output without any waiting. I investigated some more to see if it was in fact my code or the output so I downloaded ZeroBane IDE and there it works as intended but I don't want to use that because it really hurts my eyes and I feel more comfortable with Visual Studio Code